# Proof involving product of a family of classes

Tags: functions

Potentially relevant passages from in-chapter: "Let $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ be an indexed family, and, for each $i\in I$, let $x_i\in A_i$. We will use the symbol $\{x_i\}_{i\in I}$ to designate the element in $\Pi_{i\in I}A_i$ whose $i$-coordinate, for each $i\in I$, is $x_i$."

Problem statement, as written:

In the next three exercises (exercises 4, 5, and 6), assume the following:
$\cup_{i\in I}A_i = \cup_{j\in J}B_j = X$.

4. Suppose that $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ and $\{B_i\}_{i\in I}$ are nonempty classes with the same index class, $I$. Prove that if $\Pi_{i\in I}A_i \subseteq \Pi_{i\in I}B_i$, then $A_i \subseteq B_i$ for each index, $i$.

Attempted proof:
I know the gist for the proof: take arbitrary $i_0\in I$ and let $x\in A_{i_0}$ be arbitrary. If we can find an element (i.e., function), say, $f$, in $\Pi_{i\in I}A_i$ such that $f(i_0) = x$, then we can conclude that $f\in \Pi_{i\in I}B_i$, whence we may conclude that $f(i_0) = x\in B_{i_0}$. Hence, as $x$ is arbitrary, we have shown that $A_{i_0} \subseteq B_{i_0}$. Since $i_0\in I$ is arbitrary, this proves the final result, that $A_i \subseteq B_i$ for each index, $i\in I$.

My qualm is: how may I define some such $f$ with the desired property? The problem statement indicates that the families consist of nonempty classes. Thus, for each $i\in I$ there surely exists some $y\in A_i$. How can I express this formally? Based on my first paragraph above, quoted from the in-chapter text, could I simply state, "Let $\{x_i\}_{i\in I}\in \Pi_{i\in I}A_i$ such that the $x_i$. The remaining $x_i$ exist by the nonempty feature of the families of classes. But how can I specify the functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you would just write: for each $i \neq i_0$ the class $A_i$ is non-empty, so fix an arbitrary element $x_i \in A_i$. Then define $f \in \prod_{i \in I} A_i$ as $f(i_0) = x$ and $f(i) = x_i$ for $i \neq i_0$.

However, doing it formally (which is sometimes expected) requires the use of the Axiom of Choice. One of the equivalent formulations of this axiom is that a product of any family of non-empty sets is non-empty. Using it to the family $\{ A_i : i \in I \}$, we get that there exists $g \in \prod_{i \in I} A_i$. Now just define $f \in \prod_{i \in I} A_i$ as

$$f(i) = \begin{cases} x & \text{if } i = i_0 \\ g(i) & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$